# Python - list.remove while iterating on the list

Tags: python, arrays, directory, removeall

In python I came across a problem with the list.remove method. It wasn't removing what logically has to be there, and huge chunks were left in the list.

```
import os

def removeAll(content):
        for afile in content:
            content.remove(afile)
        return content
content = removeAll(os.listdir("C:\\Windows\\System32"))
print(content)
```

But if I were to remove single content without the loop

```
content.remove(content[123]) #If this string hasn't already been removed.
```

It would work. 
**Why is this?** What's an ideal alternative for dealing with huge lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. See [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) on ways to doing this perfectly.

A list is a mutable data type. If you delete elements from it, the length (and possibly indexes of elements) of the list will change. In your second example, were you to print the length of content before and after the removal, you would see the difference, because you are not assuming the old indexes and lengths to be valid for the list.

---

Consider the example below to understand more on when this exception happens:

```
>>> content = range(4)
>>> content
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> len(content)
4
>>> count = 0
>>> length = len(content)
>>> while count < length:
...     print count, length, content, len(content)
...     content.remove(content[count])
...     count += 1
... 
0 4 [0, 1, 2, 3] 4
1 4 [1, 2, 3] 3
2 4 [1, 3] 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It is clear that the length you are iterating on is a constant, but the value of count is simply corresponding to an index position which doesn't exist in the list anymore.

---

To work around this mutable nature of a list, you can remove elements from the end of the list:

```
>>> content = range(4)
>>> count = len(content) - 1
>>> while count >= 0:
...     print count, length, content, len(content)
...     content.remove(content[count])
...     count -= 1
... 
3 4 [0, 1, 2, 3] 4
2 4 [0, 1, 2] 3
1 4 [0, 1] 2
0 4 [0] 1
>>> print content
[]
```

Or you can `pop` / `remove` the first element always, as the other answers point.

Comment: Also, `count < length` never changes - infinite loop.

Comment: @mu無 Explain why a.remove(x) when x is a legitiment value, doesn't work

Comment: So, in python 3 (i dont remember which specific version), iterating through dicts is supposed to throw an error if you attempt to pop the items. I'd considered this a bug at that point because it's not throwing an error for a list while removing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using `pop` or `remove`.

```
for file in range(len(content)):
    content.pop(0) # return 0th element in every iteration.
```

**or**

```
for file in range(len(content)):
    content.remove(content[0]) #just removes the oth element in every iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to empty a list, slice everything and replace it with nothing:

```
content[:] = []
```